# markerwithlabel.js (third party) Raw File Link Broken

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, broken-links

I have a site linking to a third party library for Google Maps, markerwithlabel.js: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js.  I unfortunately hotlinked to the google hosted code when I was making my website here: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js.  This same broken link is listed under "view raw file" in the file info section of the first link.

The link suddenly stopped working at least a week (if not more) ago.  Was this code permanently taken off?  Is this a temporary issue?  I have to work with my host to change the link to a locally saved version of the library (which means coughing up $), so I'm just trying to figure out what went wrong here and if this link will ever work again.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find markerwithlabel.js   on github

```
https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library
```

under the subdir you can find all the googlemaps-v3-utilities you need

the old http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js seems no longer supported ..